# iOS5: How to calculate shortest car route

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5

I'm building an app that will calculate fuel consumption and I was wondering whats the best way to calculate the shortest car route between two locations. I only need the distance in km or miles, and don't need a map interface.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for this might be to integrate with the Google Maps API.

See here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsRequests

In summary, you will make a HTTP request to a URL containing your start/end locations, receive back either a JSON or XML which details the route. If all you are interested in is the distance, you can just grab the total distance or time from that easily enough.

Answer (score -1):

Just use this

```
CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:someLatitude longitude:someLongitude];
CLLocation *loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:anotherLatitude longitude:anotherLongitude];
CLLocationDistance dist = [loc distanceFromLocation:loc2];
float fMiles = dist/1600;
```

Comment: It reads as if he wants the 'car route', which means some sort of integration with Maps (while not actually displaying a map)

Comment: This is the distance between the two locations by tracing a line between them that follows the curvature of the Earth.